# Benefit of BYOL vs AWS provided licenses

Tags: amazon-web-services

Assuming that I have several launched EC2 instances that run Windows, SQL Server with AWS provided licenses. It means I don't have to pay for license. Is there any benefit to BYOL from on-premise to AWS in this case?

Thanks

Comment: When Amazon handles the license for you, they have to charge you more in order to cover the cost of the license. When you bring your own license, you would expect to pay Amazon less for the server, since you covered the cost of the license. However if you are just using on-demand, non-dedicated, EC2 instances then I don't think BYOL is even an option.

Comment: See [Is Windows Server eligible for BYOL on EC2?](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/faq/#windows-server-byol-ec2) and, more generally, the [Amazon Web Services and Microsoft](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/faq/) FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that I have several launched EC2 instances that run Windows, SQL Server with AWS provided licenses. It means I don't have to pay for license.

You pay for the licenses if you run Windows Server or SQL Server on EC2. They are already factored into the instance price.

If you compare the hourly price for Windows instances vs. Linux instances on the [Amazon EC2 On-Demand Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) page, you'll find that Windows-based instances are slightly more expensive than Linux-based instances.

For example, the hourly cost of running Windows Server on EC2 on a t3.medium instance in us-east-1 is $0.06, while running Linux on the same instance costs only $0.0416.

Bring-Your-Own-License (BYOL)can save you money by enabling you to leverage your existing server-bound software license investments (e.g., Windows Server, Windows SQL Server, and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server) within EC2, subject to your license terms.

Having that said, to my knowledge, BYOL is only available on Amazon dedicated hosts, which are physical servers with EC2 instance capacity fully dedicated to your use

Comment: Thanks Dennis, could you please elaborate on why BYOL can save money, subject to your license terms? In this case, I think we have already had AWS provided licenses